# ng-href doesn't pint correct url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to create an url on icon to download some files. In my controller I do this

```
$scope.download=download;
function download(id){
console.log("Parameters "+id);
return "......"+id;
}
```

In my html I do this:

```
<a title="download" ng-href="{{ download(file.id) }}" target="_blank" ><i
                            alt="download" class="fa fa-download fa-2x"></i></a>
```

The problem is the icon  doesn't have the url (because is empty) an in my console I don't read "`Parameters "+id`, It seems that `download method` is not called. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.download = function download(id){ ... }` ?

Comment: consider also renaming `$scope.download` into something more meaningful like `$scope.createDownloadLink`

Comment: @Michal_Szulc thank I'm tring and I know you if it is correct

Comment: @Michal_Szulc it doesn't work : It doesn't enter in method, the <a> has the nh-href attribute empty! :(

Comment: Have you also tried renaming funciton or just pointing to String (not a function)?

Comment: I triead also this:( put  a string to ) $scope.download='"......"/sd...; and modify my html in this way  ng-href="{{ download(file.id) }}"</code>